# Unable to set GridView row widths on RowDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net

My current code to attempt to set widths for the rows on a gridview is:

```
protected void RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                foreach (DataControlFieldHeaderCell dcfhc in e.Row.Cells)
                {
                    dcfhc.Width = 100;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (DataControlFieldCell dcfc in e.Row.Cells)
                {
                    dcfc.Width = 100;
                }
            }
        }
```

But that just keep all of the widths default! What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I have already tried thise code as well!

```
PoolToDBHeaders.DataSource = new DataView(headerTable);
        PoolToDBHeaders.DataBind();
        foreach (DataControlField dcf in PoolToDBHeaders.Columns)
        {
            dcf.ItemStyle.Width = 100;
        }
        PoolToDBHeaders.DataBind();
```

Comment: Did you mean Height? Or Perhaps column widths?

Comment: Column width, I edited with code I tried to use to set column widths which also doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...why are you setting the widths in a databinding event? Just set them (using the `Columns` property of the DataGrid) before databinding in the first place.

Setting them in a databinding event is silly anyways, since you can't possibly have different widths for different rows.

Comment: I editied the question with code I have already tried which I beleive is what you were talking about, that also doesnt work!

Comment: @jacobnlsn: Define "doesn't work". Do you get an error? Are you sure `DataControlField` is the correct type? Isn't `DataGridColumn` enough?

Comment: I am using a GridView, and there does not exist an object GridViewColumn, doesn't work means, doesnt modify the gridview after the code runs through the for loop.

Comment: @jacobnlsn: Woops, seems I'm a sloppy reader... I thought you were using DataGrid all along. To be honest, I don't see why your code shouldn't work. Did you look at the outputted source and see if the widths get outputted properly? (And why are you calling `DataBind` twice?)

Comment: From the OnRowDataBound method, it actually sets <td style="width: 100px;"><td> but yet it doesn't actually render 100px wide...